# "They are hard to play against" or "It is hard to play against them"

Tags: sentence-choice

> It's hard to play against them.

Can we rewrite it the following way -

> They are hard to play against.

Is one of the two more appropriate? Which one would you choose here?

Comment: Dummy **it** for me, the second one.  It's hard to play against them because they're hard to beat.  But it's not more "appropriate", just my idiolect.

Comment: @L.White, which one would you choose, and why? You can add that you your question...

Answer (score 2):

They are both grammatically correct and it would be difficult to choose between them. Some people have learned that they should not put a preposition (like "against") at the end of a sentence, but most people these days think that it's fine.